# How to read the top 3(the latest) threads present in an email using python

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, win32com

I was able to parse through the emails body that is present in a particular directory but it is trying to read all the threads the email has. The code I used to read the files from a directory is as follows. How to get only the top 3 threads present in an email.

```
#reading multiple .msg files using python
from pathlib import Path
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
# Assuming E:\emails\ is the directory containg files
for p in Path(r'E:\emails\').iterdir():
    if p.is_file() and p.suffix == '.msg':
        msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(p)
        print(msg.Body)
        print('-------------------------------')
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any method or property for that. You need to parse the message body on your own. I'd suggest using regular expressions for that.